# How to make a List of Generic Interfaces with Types

Tags: c#, generics, interface, return-type

Here is my code guys.

```
public interface IScorecardRule { }
public interface IScorecardRule<T> : IScorecardRule 
{
    List<T> Extract();
}

public class AdminRule : IScorecardRule<AdminRepository>
{
    public List<AdminRepository> Extract()
    {
        return new List<AdminRepository>();
    }
}

public class AdminRepository
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

Now what I want is to create a List of `IScorecardRule` interface and iterate each rule that implements it. I plan to add more rules here as per requirement each one with diff implementation of 'Extract' Method which returns `List<T>`. The problem here is that `Extract` Method is not accessible.

```
var rules = new List<IScorecardRule>();
rules.Add(new AdminRule()); //Rule for Admin
//rules.Add(new DeveloperRule()); //Rule for Developer

foreach (var rule in rules)
{
     var myList = rule.Extract(); //Extract Method Not Accessible
     //--More Code here--//
}
```

I hope it makes sense. Let me know if my logic is flawed and whether this approach is possible or not. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain me what did you want to obtain? This code looks strange to me.

Comment: You have a `List<IScorecardRule>`, a list of objects implementing an interface without any methods. So you can't call any methods on items you obtain from said list, apart from methods defined on `System.Object`. Either create a `List<IScorecardRule<AdminRepository>>`, or better explain what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Can you try replacing the line where you call the Extract method with this? `((IScorecardRule)rule).Extract();`

Comment: `Extract` is not defined in `IScorecardRule`, which is the type you've defined for your `List`...remember that `IScorecardRule` is different than `IScorecardRule<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the first line:

```
var rules = new List<IScorecardRule>();
```

You're declaring the list as `IScorecardRule` instead of `IScorecardRule<AdminRepository>`

Since the extract method isn't in the `IScorecardRule` interface it can't be seen.

Answer (score -2):

I just managed to solve this problem by using the code below. The solution is not pretty though but I'll just leave this one here.

```
foreach (var rule in rules)
{
    Type typeParameterType = rule.GetType();
    var instance = (dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(typeParameterType);
    var myList = instance.Extract();
}
```